# download the contents from child iframes upto 5 levels using nodejs,

Tags: javascript, node.js

I keep getting

> Uncaught Error: This Fiber is not yielding

What I want to do is to download the contents inside iframe tag upto 5 levels i.e

```
  Main page  <iframe src = "http://test.com"></iframe>
  Child Page <iframe src = "http://child.com"></iframe> //download contents from http://test.com
  Grand page <iframe src = "http://grandchild.com"></iframe> // download contents from child.com
```

My Trans.js

```
var iframes = jquery("iframe");
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        //Get a Jquery wrapper for Iframe
        var src = jquery(iframes[i]);
        // look for src attribute
        var Srcurl = src.attr('src');

// make HTTP Request and get the body content

        var GetBody = sync.fiber(function(url){
            var r = sync.await(tempo.connect(url, sync.defer())); //download the contents using Cheerio
            return [null, r.response, r.body];
        });

        var ParentData = GetBody(Srcurl);

        var ParentBody = ParentData[2];
        console.log(ParentBody);
        var LoadParentWithCheerio = cheerio.load(ParentBody);
        var ChildIframe = LoadParentWithCheerio("iframe"); 

        for(var j=0;j<ChildIframe.length;j++){
            // Child Source
            var ChildIframeSrc = ChildIframe.attr('src');
            // get the child data
            var ChildData = GetBody(ChildIframeSrc);
            var ChildBodyData = ChildData[2];
            console.log(ChildBodyData);
        }
    }
};
```

I cannot call GetBody morethan ones it works upto first lvl but then it fails if i call morethan ones... How could I make it working..???

I have also tried wrapping up the entire for loop inside for loop. its still the same error.

More info:

I am using "cheerio" to download the contents from the url and to sync i use synchronizeJS.